# How to open multiple external URLs in one button click but not get blocked by browsers popup blocker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How to open multiple external URLs in one button click but not get blocked by browsers popup blocker? [specially Chrome]

Comment: how we can do with anchor tags?

Comment: Why would you want to spawn several new windows. I can only think of one category of websites which is doing that. Opening new windows is really outdated.

Comment: i guess some e-com site which will keep firing unlimited adds.

Comment: I am not really planning to open multiple windows/tabs for ads. But am creating a web app that allows users to open multiple predefined websites (i.e. http://www.google.com, http://www.facebook.com, http://www.megasearches.com etc.) in one button click like some browser extensions do (SessionBudddy, MorningCoffee etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `onclick` event for any anchor tags with multiple `windows.open` for opening the links in new window/tab.

```
<a href="http://bloggersentral.blogspot.com/" target="_blank" onclick="window.open(&quot;http://www.tourism.gov.my/&quot;); window.open(&quot;http://www.tic.kelantan.gov.my/&quot;);">This anchor opens three links in a single click</a>
```

Above anchor will open three links in single click.you can write multiple `window.open` for same.

Comment: I tried this approach, but the problem is that after first window is open normally (in a tab or window, depending on user's browser preferences) the rest of the windows opens as popups and browser blocks them as popup. Even if the user allows the popups to open, the windows are not full normal windows/tabs.

Comment: I found a solution !!! But it requires to have user's input as the browsers tackle the problems of unwanted popups. You can instruct the user to click the anchor/button that opens multiple URLs while holding the "ctrl" key (Windows) or "cmd" key (Mac). This approach will open all the URLss in tabs/windows in the background without creating any popups.

Answer (score 1):

Use onclick where u can write multiple window.open , with in a single onclick that will opens the respective urls specified.....

Comment: I have tried at least 10 different ways, but no luck. Most of the browsers (specially Chrome, Opera) opens the first site normally as tab/window but the rest of the sites are opened as popups.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="http://bloggersentral.blogspot.com/" target="_blank" 
 onclick="window.open(&quot;http://www.tourism.gov.my/&quot;); 
 window.open(&quot;http://www.tic.kelantan.gov.my/&quot;);">This anchor opens three links in a single click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are popup blockers in place, you cannot open them in new windows. You can however target iFrames

Answer (score 0):

If I needed this I would open several internal pages and each of these pages would contain just iframe with targeted site.

Comment: I cannot use iFrames, because all the sites are external links and need to be opened as normal tabs/windows. Not popups, not iFrames

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to unblock the pop up windows for your browser and the code could work.

> chrome://settings/contentExceptions#popups

[image: Chrome browser setting]